# How to get continuous sliding effect of images and text as if a video is playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to build the slider in Jquery/JavaScript where I can able to slide images and texts simultaneously with fade effect.

Please see this link for reference [linde.com](http://www.linde.in/en/index.html)

Anyone suggest me how can we get this effect same as in the link provided above.

Comment: @adeneo I am trying to do that in jquery/Javascript I already have knowledge in Flash, But that is not what I meant....

Comment: `Questions asking for code` **`must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.`** `Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results` sorry dude.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight please check this fiddle I have tried this as a inital start up to this. I am not familiar with Jquery/Javascript that is why I came here for some help. If anyone might have already worked on this would answer!

Comment: what fiddle? i dont c one.

Comment: Sorry check this link http://jsfiddle.net/XpAjZ/

Comment: @adreno a person with 68k reputation should have commented like that...i meant the first comment..you can do it easily with jquery/js..he has also tagged those only not flash..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `WOW Slider`.Hope this helps you out

Following are links...the effect you mean is kenburns effect.

http://wowslider.com/banner-maker-geometric-kenburns-demo.html

http://wowslider.com/jquery-slider-bar-kenburns-demo.html

Comment: no problem..pleasure..